# Tmux change to the next session conf file

Tags: linux, tmux

I want to change my tmux.conf file to change to the next and previous session with cntrl+shift+0 and cntrl+shift+9 respectively. But i don't know how to get the next and previous session target.

This is what i have so far:

```
bind -n C-S-0 attach-session -t ganache
```

but doesn't work of course and the target session isn't dinamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are built in key-bindings to do this (see `tmux list-keys`):

```
Ctrl )
Ctrl (
```

But you can rebind the switches between existing sessions, just do:

```
bind 'C-S-0' switch-client -n
bind 'C-S-9' switch-client -p
```

So then you would do `Ctrl+b` + `Ctrl+Shift+0` to switch to next and `Ctrl+b` +
`Ctrl+Shift+9` to switch to previous.

Apparently you can add an `-r` flag to not require the prefix before the
command... but for some reason I can't get that to work for me... but maybe I
have something interfering. Here is what should work (if I understood):

```
bind -r 'C-S-0' switch-client -n
bind -r 'C-S-9' switch-client -p
```

However, note from the tmux man page that this is not recommended:

> bind-key [-nr] [-T key-table] key command [arguments] 
> (alias: bind) 
> Bind key key to command.  Keys are bound in a key table.  By default (without -T), the key is bound in the prefix key table.  This table is
> used for keys pressed after the prefix key (for example, by default ‘c’ is bound to new-window in the prefix table, so ‘C-b c’ creates a new
> window).  The root table is used for keys pressed without the prefix key: binding ‘c’ to new-window in the root table (not recommended) means
> a plain ‘c’ will create a new window.  -n is an alias for -T root.  Keys may also be bound in custom key tables and the switch-client -T com‐
> mand used to switch to them from a key binding.  The -r flag indicates this key may repeat, see the repeat-time option.
>
> To view the default bindings and possible commands, see the list-keys command.

Comment: The "-r" allows the key to repeat.
If you want to add the binding to the root table you can use "-Troot" or the shortcut "-n".